# What happens when I call a function passed as props in nested React components?

Tags: reactjs, prop

I'm trying to understand how nested props in React work.
If I have a component A who's parent of a component B who's parent of a component C.
A gives to B a prop `foo()`, B gives to C the prop `foo()` it got from A.

I call `foo()` inside C. What happens?

1)C's `foo()` calls B's `foo()` who calls A's `foo()`
2)C's `foo()` acts the same as A's `foo()` because it IS A's `foo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that in component A you have a function `foo`

```
foo(string) {
    console.log(string)
}
```

and In `A` you render component `B` and pass `foo` as a prop

```
<ComponetB foo={this.foo}/>
```

and the same thing for `B`

```
<ComponetC foo={this.foo}/>
```

and in component `C` you call

```
this.props.foo('hey')
```

this will call component `A` function, that will make an `console.log('hey')`

You can pass `foo` as a prop to how many components you want and it will execute what is in the parent component ( `A` ).

If you will pass something to many nested components, you can use [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Context API will pass a value to all children's of you component as a prop. You should read the documentation to learn more about that.